# Tentando preencher um array com dias de hoje até daqui a trinta dias

Tags: javascript

Olá, pessoal, estou tentando preencher um array com dias desde o dia atual até daqui a 30 dias.

Eis que surge um problema: se hoje é dia 8, daqui a 30 dias será 38, mas quero que a contagem volte para 1 a partir do dia máximo de cada mês. Para contornar isso, to tentando usar a seguinte lógica:

```
//busca o dia de hoje e preenche o array com os dias de hoje + 30 dias
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var somaTrinta = dd + 30;
     //vetor que possui o máximo de dias por cada mês
     var diasPorMes = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
     var mm = today.getMonth();
     var maximoDias = diasPorMes[mm];
     var i;

     for(i = dd; i < somaTrinta; i++) {
       if (i > maximoDias) {
         i = 1;
       }
       horizontal.push(i);       
     }
```

Porém, após inserir o if, a página nem carrega mais. Não sei qual é o meu erro, tem como alguém me ajudar? Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando apenas a [instancia Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do *javascript* já é o suficiente para chegar ao resultado que deseja.

```
var hoje = new Date(); // Crio uma data
hoje.setMonth(hoje.getMonth() +1); // aplico mais um mês

var dias = [];
//percorro os dias até chegar a dia do mês seguinte
for (var dia = new Date(); dia <= hoje; dia.setDate(dia.getDate() + 1)) {
    dias.push(dia.getDate()); //salvo em um array
}
console.log(dias);
```

Comment: Obrigado DNick, realmente resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar o `setDate()` para ir mudando um objeto data e depois saber o dia com `getDate()`.

```js
var dias = 30;
var hoje = new Date();
var primeiroDia = hoje.getDate();
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dias; i++) {
  hoje.setDate(primeiroDia + i)
  array.push(hoje.getDate());
}
console.log(array);
```

Outra maneira, seguindo a mesma lógica:

```js
var data = new Date();
var hoje = data.getDate();
var array = [...new Array(30)].map(
  (_, i) => (data.setDate(hoje + i), data.getDate())
);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Outro método para conseguir isso é pegar ano, mês e dia de hoje, e fazer um loop incrementando apenas o dia. Quando você passa um dia com data acima do que tem o mês, por exemplo 32 de Janeiro, o construtor de `Date` muda automaticamente:

```
//busca o dia de hoje e preenche o array com os dias de hoje + 30 dias
var hoje = new Date();
var ano = hoje.getFullYear();
var mes = hoje.getMonth();
var dia = hoje.getDate();
var dias = []; // array de dias
for(var i = dia; i <= dia + 30; i++) {
  dias.push(new Date(ano, mes, i));
}
```

Veja ele funcionando aqui: https://fiddle.jshell.net/kvg3ht3d/1/